# The hello_tutorial doesn't build with pepper_29

Tags: google-nativeclient

run make inside the hello_tutorial directory. I got an error:

nacl_sdk/pepper_29/toolchain/mac_x86_newlib/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-nacl/4.4.3/../../../../x86_64-nacl/bin/ld: cannot find -lppapi_cpp
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

I'm using Mac.

Any idea?

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for the report. There have been some changes in the SDK structure recently and the `Makefile` example has to be updated. You can download an updated example [from here](http://goo.gl/qosk46) (direct `.zip` link). We'll update the example linked from the documentation in a day or two.

Comment: Just fell into this hole - the example linked from the documentation still fails in pepper_31 4 months later, whereas your direct link works fine.  Time to update the documentation link perhaps?

Comment: @PaulDelhanty: thanks for reporting, we'll look into it